# How to count triplets of i,j,k such that i < j < k

Tags: python, counting

I want to know an efficient way of calculating the count of triplets `i`, `j`, and `k` such that `i < j < k`.

I've tried using the following code:

```
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i + 1, n):
    for k in range(j + 1, n):
      ans += 1
```

But that would result in O(N<sup>3</sup>) time complexity and that is not very efficient. O(N log N) time complexity (or faster) would be optimal.

Comment: this is  a math problem, not a program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any loops. There is a [closed form formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5B1%2C%7Bk%2Cj%2B1%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2Ci%2B1%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bi%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D) for this:

[image: 1/6 n(n**2 - 3n + 2)]

Or:

[image: 1/6 (n - 2)(n - 1)n]